# node.js, expressJS - cannot read properly the cookie value holding an array of objects

Tags: jquery, node.js, cookies, express

My app uses, node.js , expressJS, jQuery.Using the jQuery [cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) plugin, I created a cookie from client side and then could read it successfully. I wanted to read that cookie from server side(node.js, express js) as well but could not.

```
var products_cart=new Array();



for(var i =1; i<5; i++){
var prod_cart_indiv= new Object();  

prod_cart_indiv.prod_id=i;

prod_cart_indiv.price=(200+i);
prod_cart_indiv.num_total=(4+i);
prod_cart_indiv.name='printing products _ '+i;
prod_cart_indiv.img='a_'+i+'.jpg';

products_cart.push(prod_cart_indiv);

}// end of for loop
$.cookie('products_cart',JSON.stringify(products_cart));
var products_cart_found =JSON.parse($.cookie('products_cart'));

if(window.console){


    console.log("Logging products_cart_found ");

    console.dir(products_cart_found);

}
```

The server side node.js code :

```
var util = require('util');
 app.get('*',function(req,res){

 var get_cookies = function(request) {
  var cookies = {};
  request.headers && request.headers.cookie.split(';').forEach(function(cookie) {
    var parts = cookie.match(/(.*?)=(.*)$/)
    cookies[ parts[1].trim() ] = (parts[2] || '').trim();
  });
  return cookies;
};

 var products_cart_found= get_cookies(req)['products_cart'];

 console.log(util.inspect(products_cart_found, false, null));

});
```

What I found in command prompt is :

```
'%5B%7B%22prod_id%22%3A1%2C%22price%22%3A201%2C%22num_total%22%3A5%2C%22name%22%
    3A%22printing%20products%20_%201%22%2C%22img%22%3A%22a_1.jpg%22%7D%2C%7B%22prod_
    id%22%3A2%2C%22price%22%3A202%2C%22num_total%22%3A6%2C%22name%22%3A%22printing%2
    0products%20_%202%22%2C%22img%22%3A%22a_2.jpg%22%7D%2C%7B%22prod_id%22%3A3%2C%22
    price%22%3A203%2C%22num_total%22%3A7%2C%22name%22%3A%22printing%20products%20_%2
    03%22%2C%22img%22%3A%22a_3.jpg%22%7D%2C%7B%22prod_id%22%3A4%2C%22price%22%3A204%
    2C%22num_total%22%3A8%2C%22name%22%3A%22printing%20products%20_%204%22%2C%22img%
    22%3A%22a_4.jpg%22%7D%5D'
```

whereas in the browser console, I got the output below (handcrafted to make presentable):

```
Array[4] 
 Object: img: "a_1.jpg"name: "printing products _ 1"num_total: 5price: 201prod_id: 1
 Object: img: "a_2.jpg"name: "printing products _ 2"num_total: 6price: 202prod_id: 2
 Object: Objectimg: "a_3.jpg"name: "printing products _ 3"num_total: 7price: 203prod_id: 3
 Object: Objectimg: "a_4.jpg"name: "printing products _ 4"num_total: 8price: 204prod_id: 4
```

How can I get the cookie value in a variable so that I  can iterate over it as if it were an array of objects>

Comment: Install the cookieparser, and use that -> https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser

Comment: @adeneo, actually tried that but got the value to be `undefined`. How to use the middleware - on the returned value I got ?

Comment: Your custom cookie parsing doesn't appear to be doing `JSON.parse()` on the value it finds, yet you did `JSON.stringify()` when you created it.  I agree with adeneo that I'm using the `cookieparser()` and it does all the cookie work for me.  The doc fully explains how to configure it.

Comment: @jfriend00, could  solve with the `cookie-parser` middleware. Can you show where and how to use the `JSON.parse` ?